# Unexpected Tokens on Test Class for Apex Trigger: What am I doing wrong to create a test class for this Trigger trying to deploy to Production?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class, deployment-error

```
@isTest 
public class LeadRemovalTestClass
{
    Static testmethod void updateRecord()
        
              trigger UpdateLeadOnRemoval on ActionCadenceTrackerChangeEvent (after insert) {
    
    for(ActionCadenceTrackerChangeEvent event : Trigger.New) {
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;
        List<String> recordIds = header.getRecordIds();
        
        System.debug('Received change event for ' + 
                     header.entityName +
                     ' for the ' + 
                     header.changeType + 
                     ' operation.'
                    );
        
        System.debug('Received change event for ' + 
                     event.ChangeEventHeader
                    );
        
        if(recordIds.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        
        // Get ActionCadenceTracker records where the target is a lead and Manually Removed
        List<ActionCadenceTracker> cadenceTrackers = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, CurrencyIsoCode, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, ActionCadenceId, TargetId, CurrentStepId, State, CompletionReason, LastCompletedStepId, ErrorMessage, ExitGlobalRuleId, RelatedToId, RelatedToAttributionType, CompletionDisposition, ScheduledResumeDateTime, IsTrackerActive, DaisyChainIteration FROM ActionCadenceTracker
                                                       WHERE Id IN :recordIds 
                                                             AND CompletionReason = 'ManuallyRemoved'
                                                             AND Target.Type = 'Lead'];

        if(cadenceTrackers != null && cadenceTrackers.size() > 0) {
            System.debug('Found ' + cadenceTrackers.size() + ' Cadence tracker events.');
            
            List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
            for(ActionCadenceTracker cadenceTracker : cadenceTrackers) {
                System.debug('Adding the lead ID  ' + cadenceTracker.TargetId + ' to Lead list.');
                Lead lead = new Lead(Id=cadenceTracker.TargetId,Status='Unqualified');
                if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Contact Later') {
                        lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Not Right Now';
                        lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Timing Isnt Right';
                } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'No response') {
                    lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Not Right Now';
                    lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Never responsive/no insights';
    
    
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Not Interested') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Not Right Now';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Never responsive/no insights';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Disqualified') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Not Right Now';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Never responsive/no insights';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Bad Data') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Bad Data';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Wrong Phone Number';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Duplicate') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Bad Data';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Existing record/duplicate';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Current Solution Meets Needs') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Current Solution Meets Needs';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Using Manual Process';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Budget') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Budget';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Cant afford at this time';
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Lacks Critical Features') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Lacks Critical Features';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = null;
                
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Prospects accountant doesnt want to switch') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Prospects accountant doesnt want to switch';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = 'Prospects accountant doesnt want to switch';
                    
                
            } else if (cadenceTracker.CompletionDisposition == 'Using/Going with Competitor') {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = 'Using/Going with Competitor';
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = null;
                
                
            } else {
                lead.Reason_why_Unqualified__c = null;
                lead.Detailed_Reason_Unqualified__c = null;
            }
                leads.add(lead);
            }          
            update leads;
        } else {
            System.debug('Did not find any Manually Removed Cadences that are related to leads');
        }
    }
}
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix trigger code and unit test code into a single file. The "unexpected tokens" error comes from the fact that two files were apparently mixed together. You should have at least two files, `LeadRemovalTestClass` and `UpdateLeadOnRemoval`. The first file should be an Apex Class and start off with `@isTest class LeadRemovalTestClass`, and the second should be an Apex Trigger that starts with `trigger UpdateLeadOnRemoval on ActionCadenceTrackerChangeEvent (after insert)`. The unit test should have a method in it reading `@isTest static void updateRecord()` or such. Note that `testmethod` is deprecated and should not be used in new code.